# Is there any function/code to prevent saving duplicate values in the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website where subtitles are translated and where it is possible to save translated subtitles to mysql database.

In the database I have a table consisting of 2 significant columns:
"name" and
"langugage"

When a user who save their subtitle is obliged to enter the subtitle "name" and the "language" is selected automatically.
So I need a code or function that I can insert via phpmyadmin or in my php file, so that when a user try to save subtitle in the "name" column that exists and when a language is selected in the "Language" column that already exists with the same "name" and in the same "language", a message appears to the user that it cannot save that subtitle because it already exists in the database and prevent user for saving the srt file.

php file:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1000);
include "config.php";
include  'vendor/mantas-done/subtitles/src/Subtitles.php';
use \Done\Subtitles\Subtitles;
$subtitles = new Subtitles();

$data =  $_POST['data'];
$file_name =  $_POST['file'];
$subtitle =  $_POST['subtitle'];
$language =  $_POST['language'];
$author =  $_POST['author'];
$ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER)) {
    $ip = array_pop(explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']));
}


$data =json_decode($data, true);

foreach($data as $obj){

    $subtitles->add($obj['start'], $obj['end'],$obj['text']);
    $subtitles->save($file_name);
}
$ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$new_file_name_ext = time()."_".$subtitle."_".$language.".".$ext;
$new_file_name = time()."_".$subtitle."_".$language;
$query1 = "INSERT INTO movies (name , author, language, filename, user_ip)
            VALUES ('$subtitle','$author', '$language', '$new_file_name', '$ip')";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $query1)){
    copy("$file_name", "uploads_iota/$new_file_name_ext");
    //new GoodZipArchive('uploads_iota/$new_file_name',    'upload_iota/output_zip_file.zip') ;
    $data1 = "Successful, File saved to database.";

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $new_zip = time()."_".$subtitle."_".$language.".zip";
    if ($zip->open("uploads_zip/$new_zip", ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
    {
        $zip->addFile("uploads_iota/$new_file_name_ext", "$new_file_name_ext");
        $zip->close();
    }
} else{
    $data1 = mysqli_error();
}

echo $data1; ?>
```

Comment: Validation (on the PHP side) or unique keys (on the MySQL) or a combination of the two.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: You have an error. `mysqli_error()` needs one argument. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: Darmna , ok how can I prevent SQL injection ?

Answer (score 3):

Generally you do this kind of thing by creating a unique index on the two columns where uniqueness is enforced. It's `(name,language)` in this case.

Try this command, when you create your table, to make this index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name_language_unique ON movies(name, language);
```

Then, your `INSERT` function generates an SQL error when your user tries to insert a forbidden duplicate. You can detect that error and inform the user.

Comment: Worth to mention that composite index like this won't work for strings with sum length over 255 characters

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I think is to create an index of the fields.

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table_name`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `name_language` (`name`, `languaje`) USING BTREE;
```

and the other way that I can think of is doing:

```
SELECT COUNT(name) AS count WHERE name='your_value' AND languaje='your_languaje';
```

and validating it in PHP, verifying that the count is 0.
I hope it helps you ;)